# What's the origin of the phrase "build bridges?"

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

I often come across the phrase "build bridges" and I'm keen to know the origin of this phrase.

I've done a lot of research on the Internet (plus in some books). Neither [Theidioms.com]( [theidioms.com/build-bridges](https://www.theidioms.com/build-bridges/) nor [Phrases.org.uk](https://phrases.org.uk) have anything useful.

Comment: _Bridge builder_ is a literal translation of the Latin word [_pontifex_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pontifex#Latin), defined by Wiktionary as "1.   a high priest, State minister in ancient Rome. 2. a pontiff or bishop of the early Christian church, now specifically the Pope". Thus the phrase is centuries older than English.

Comment: Interesting story Colin, thanks for sharing. In which words can I satisfy readers seeking its origin? I am not getting it. Can you help?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't want to bet money that idiomatic ***build bridges*** predates ***burn bridges*** (though presumably *building* would always have to come first for the ***literal*** sense! :)

Comment: @ColinFine Maybe there are many people like me seeking its origin. Which words or story can end their search?

Comment: ...but I'll just point out that the full OED has its first citation for ***burn bridges*** as 1745, whereas they've got a 1719 cite for *burn one's **boats***. And their first cite for metaphoric ***build bridges*** is 1886.

Comment: 'Mazing that burn bridges should have been used before build bridges! You have to have built the bridge (connection) before burning (destroying) it. Hope I don't burn my bridges with esteemed users of English here!